# how to make NGINX serve static content like .js, .css, .html?

Tags: css, windows, tomcat, nginx, jboss

Recently I have started using NGINX, I found that we can use it for reverse proxy, serving static content from itself which can reduce load time. I have a Tomcat/JBoss server on my local machine and I want to put NGINX in front of it so that static content will be served from NGINX and rest all by Tomcat/JBoss. My Tomcat/JBoss application is running on `http://localhost:8081/Test` my NGINX configuration worked properly but it is not able to load `css/js/jpg` file. Here is my war strcuture wehere static contents are

Test.war

```
TEST
  |
  |--->Resources
  |       |------->CSS
  |       |         |----> style.css
  |       |
  |       |-------->Images
  |                  |----> a.jpg
  |                  |----> b.jpg
  |   
  |--->WEB-INF
  |        |----->Web.xml
  |        |----->spring-servlet.xml
  |
  |--->JSP
         |---->login.jsp
```

I think the problem is because of absolute path, so should I copy resources folder and put it in some folder in NGINX and configure my NGINX to pick file from its own directory rather going to Tomcat/JBoss? I am new so I dont have any idea of doing this can anyone pls help me in this. This is my conf file for NGINX(windows)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/Test/;
        }
```

Comment: Adding a more specific location `/Resources/` that you point at the absolute path should work. (you need to point it at the exploded war folder)

Comment: so I should put a Resources folder in my NGINX server directory?

Comment: actually what I am thinking is to put all my static content in NGINX server directory and they should be served from here instead of loading them from JBoss/Tomcat but I dont know how to configure NGINX to load all these static content from its own server directory

Comment: That should also work. But you need to stop the proxy_pass from being effective. Define a more specific location.

Comment: @Thilo: Do you have any sample conf file where you did this to look for static content in NGINX directory and rest all to JBoss directory???

Comment: do you really need to do that? You cannot limit the paths (for example to /Resources)?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you, anyways I will try this and will let you know

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add **location** with regexp:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root path/to/tomcat/document/root/Test/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/Test/;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to test it after set it ?

Comment: @ihue sudo service nginx restart

Comment: @ihue Test it with `sudo nginx -t` instead

Comment: I don't mean to test the nginx syntax. I mean to test the caching speed. How to check if your cache make it different?

Comment: I would also like a way to test if this works.. is there a way to track from which server the static files are served from?

Comment: How can I du that but only to request that is made under location /app ?

Answer (score 6):

**Try**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 168h;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/Test/;
    }
}
```

---

**How to test**

In your CLI run  `ab -c 20 -n 1000 https://your-site/any-file`

You will see **Time taken for tests** decrease drastically.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
location /static {
     alias /usr/src/app/project/static;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture all assets (**css,js,png...**) in one go and serve the relevant file, here is the solution by using regex groups:

```
location ~* \/([^\/]+\.)(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /path/to/assets/directory/$1$2;
     expires 30d;
}
```